# Using Media Queries

Tags: css, media

I'm trying to created a media query that displays an image if your screen resolution is between a certain size and I can't get it to work. I'm using the following:

```
<style>
@meida (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 5000px) {
<div="sixteen columns" align="center">
<div class="home-boxes"><img src="http://www.ursovain.com/wp-content/uploads/boxes-3.jpg">   
</div>
}
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome! `@meida` should be `@media`. And you shouldn't embed html elements inside a style, although they are not *really* html elements, the way you've written them. Basically I think you need to read documentation or a tutorial on HTML and CSS in general, because this piece of code is quite messed up.

Comment: You're looking for Javascript, not CSS.

Comment: A javascript solution would be using Matchmedia, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify it as in my example below. HTML and CSS are seperate.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .home-boxes {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="home-boxes">
    <img src="http://www.ursovain.com/wp-content/uploads/boxes-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

In my example above the media query will apply the CSS within it when it's screen condition is met. In this case the CSS that will be applied is `display: none` to all elements with a class of `home-boxes`